# Tensors transformations under $so(4)$

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, tensor-products

A four vector $a_i$ transforms in $SO(4)$ as $\underline{4}
 \sim(\underline{2},\underline{2})$ under the algebra $so(4)\sim su(2)\times su(2)$.
How does a symmetric tensor $a_i b_j + a_j b_i$ transform? (under $so(4)$))

A symmetric tensor has 10 independent entries, so I need to understand how a 10-dimensional representation decomposes in $su(2)\times su(2)$ and if it is irreducible I think...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Symmetric tensors are not irrecducible, they decompose into tracefree tensors (in your notation, this means $g^{ij}a_ib_j=0$ and a trace part, which must be a multiple of $g_{ij}$. Thus you get a direct sum of a trivial representation and a nine-dimensional one, which is just $(\underline{3},\underline{3})$.

Comment: Ok, now I understand. So the symmetric tensor transforms with a non-irriducibile representation $(1,1)+(3,3)$, a traceless symmetric with (3,3) and an antisimmetric with $(3,1)+(1,3)$. So when I do the tensor product $(2,2)\otimes (2,2)$ I have to to the standard $su(2)$ product first term first term and second with second without mixing the two?

Comment: There are tow different versions of tensor products here. On the one hand, you consider Lie algebras $\mathfrak g$ and $\mathfrak h$ (which happen to both be $\mathfrak su(2)$), a representation $V$ of $\mathfrak g$ and a representation $W$ of $\mathfrak h$ (which again happen to coincide) and view $V\otimes W$ as a representation of $\mathfrak g\times\mathfrak h$. This is sometimes called "exterior tensor product" and denoted by $V\boxtimes W$. Then one indeed has $(V_1\boxtimes W_1)\otimes (V_2\boxtimes W_2)\cong (V_1\otimes V_2)\boxtimes (W_1\otimes W_2)$ as representations of the product.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed to know! Is it a postulate the "$\cong$" or can it be proved?

Comment: It can be proved and this is mainly a formal verification.